# Python printing comparison result with an error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to print the statement with comparison results, but I am getting EOL while scanning literal error

```
prod = df_merge[df_merge["_merge"]=="left_only"]
len(prod)
prod 1= df_merge[df_merge["_merge"]=="right_only"]
len(prod1)
prod_results = ("""compares two tables, records in prod only are""" "+str(len(prod)+"  """and records in prod1 are:  "  +str(len(prod)+" )"""
```

I want to show the numbers at the place of +str(len(prod)+"

Comment: The last line is missing the closing parentheses `)`.  There's one inside the string, but that doesn't count because it's just text.

Comment: `df_merge["_merge]` You forgot a double quote after `_merge`.  Twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you intended:

```
prod_results = "compares two tables, records in prod only are " + str(len(prod)) + " and records in prod1 are: " + str(len(prod))
```